# Writing user input to file using tee

Tags: shell-script, ksh, read, tee

I have a script which guides users through the installation of my software and I want to write a log file in case something bad happens and the user needs support.

The script looks like this:

```
while true; do
  echo "This script will help you with the installation. Do you wish to proceed?"
  echo "(1) Yes"
  echo "(2) No"
  read proceed
  case $proceed in
    1 ) break;;
    * ) echo "Aborting."; exit 8;;
  esac
done
unset proceed
```

I then run it by using `./install.ksh | tee /var/log/myinstall.log` and everything works just fine, but the user input to the question is not logged.
When I add `echo $proceed` after the `read` command, it is written to the log but displayed twice, like that:

```
This script will help you with the installation. Do you wish to proceed?
(1) Yes
(2) No
1 #this is the input which is not written to the log
1 # this is the echo which is written to the log
```

My question is now how I could either suppress the output of the `read` command or how I could write the `echo` only to the file but not to STDOUT?

Comment: Why not just `echo "You chose $proceed, continuing"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) instead, it’s designed for exactly this purpose:

```
script /var/log/myinstall.log -c ./install.ksh
```

It will log the input to `read` as well as any output.

Comment: Now another problem occurred. I need to support AIX and the AIX korn shell does not support -c, only -a for append and -q for qiet.
Any ideas how to run it without -c?

Comment: I was going to suggest asking a new question but I see you’ve [just done that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/430389/86440) ;-).

Comment: For python or similar: `script -c "python p.py"`