# Using script command for installation script on AIX

Tags: scripting, ksh, aix

I have an installation script for my software and I need it to run on both, Linux and AIX.

On Linux I can use a wrapper `myinstaller.ksh` like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
script -c myrealinstaller.ksh /var/log/myinstaller.log
```

But on AIX `script` [does not support the `-c` option](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/script.htm).

How can I run my `myrealinstaller.ksh` inside the forked shell created by script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enhance your wrapper script to detect the OS; if it's running on Linux, execute `script -c ...`, but if it's running on AIX, give the script-shell an overridden profile that only runs your installer, then exits:

```
$ cat myinstaller.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

case $(uname -s) in
  (Linux)
        script -c myrealinstaller.ksh /var/log/myinstaller.log
        ;;
  (AIX)
        printf "ENV= ./myrealinstaller.ksh\nexit\n" > ./installer.profile
        trap 'rm -f ./installer.profile' INT
        ENV=./installer.profile script -q ./var/log/myinstaller.log
        rm ./installer.profile
        ;;
esac
```

I adjusted the paths to the script and logs to test it locally. The other factors involved are:

- setting `ENV` to point to the overridden profile as we call `script`
- calling `script` with `-q` to quiet it down a bit
- importantly, *unsetting* ENV during the call to the real installer, so that we don't loop infinitely
- telling the overridden profile to exit as soon as the installer is done

With a sample myrealinstaller.ksh of:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo Hi, I am the real installer
```

The contents of ./var/log/myinstaller.log are:

```
Script command is started on Thu Mar 15 09:34:04 2018.
Hi, I am the real installer


Script command is complete on Thu Mar 15 09:34:04 2018.
```

Comment: Nice, this works very well. The only problem I found is the installer.profile which is not removed if the real installer is interrupted by ctrl+c.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works, @P.Jksch! I've added a line to remove the installer.profile intermediate file if the user hits Control-C.